# Как отправить запрос с Nuxt в php файл?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, nuxt.js

Я пытаюсь отправить простой GET запрос в файл php, но получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расположение файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос в index.vue:

```
  async fetch() {
    try {
      const p = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/index.php", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept-Type": "application/json", },
      });

      console.log(await p.json());
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  },
```

Код index.php:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(['name' => 'Alexandr', 'age' => 51]);
```

Comment: Ну наверное же PHP сервер нужно поднять, чтобы PHP исполнялся, как считаете?

Comment: Да, спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было просто запустить php сервер с помощью команды

```
php -S localhost:5000
```

И обращаться по url `"http://localhost:5000"` в запросе